# Which API to use for realtime document collaboration

Tags: google-sheets, real-time, document, collaboration

I am currently building a virtual classroom website and so far I have successfully added webcam & audio functionality.

The next thing that is on my list is to add realtime document collaboration.

So how this would work is:

1. Two people join a private session
2. These two people have a shared document that they can both edit and changes are displayed in realtime to the other user.

An example of this would be google docs where you can be multiple people on one document.

Anyway, I have seen a few APIs that do this, for example I have looked into google docs api, but it requires you to have a google account which is not optimal. (Registering both on my website and on google docs can be a hassle or too much work for some people).

I have also looked into Zoho, but I am unsure if it can fill my needs.

Does anyone of you know an API that can do this? Preferably both document and sheets(excel looking).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Google Realtime API is especially well-suited for document collaboration, but it sounds like it's not a good fit.  There are a few other options out there:

- [ShareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb) is an open-source realtime database backend, used in the [DerbyJS](http://derbyjs.com/) framework.
- [Mozilla's TogetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/) provides view-level collaboration features.
- [Convergence](https://convergence.io) (disclaimer: I am a founder) is a new hosted platform providing APIs for this sort of functionality.  We have identified the most common pain points when implementing realtime collaboration features, and provide high-level APIs to solve them.

Comment: This is a bit of an old thread, but I recommend using [Liveblocks](https://liveblocks.io). You can quickly add real-time collaboration to your product to create experiences similar to Figma, Notion, Miro, and more.

Disclaimer: I'm the founder, but I still think this will be helpful for developers looking for a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Multiplayer](https://finalfloat.com/products/multiplayer) is concurrent editing database, it looks like it is based on Operation Transforms and they are planning to launch on Kickstarter. Looks like it can do exactly what you need, and they use Websockets to send changes in real-time.